# Do any Christian scholars contrast Islamic eschatology with Christian eschatology?

Tags: eschatology, islam

Are there any Christian scholars (and their works) that comment on Islamic eschatology, and/or contrast it with Christian eschatology? As an example of a Muslim scholar coming at this question from the opposite side, Imran Hosein wrote "Jerusalem In the Qu'ran", which looks at both Christian and Muslim eschatology from a Muslim perspective.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a little unclear what you are asking here. Are you asking for the name of a Christian scholar who has looked at Islamic Eschatology, or are you asking what his views were in regard to Islamic Eschatology?  Alternatively, are you (as the last sentence might suggest) proposing that the Islamic tradition is 'Truth' and should be accepted by Christians?  Could you elaborate on your actual meaning?

Comment: I think my question is clear, I am asking about christain scholars who looked on the Islamic Eschatology, I didn't say anything about truth or lies, why are you interpretating my question ? and i just mentioned an islamic scholar who is a reference in Islamic Eschatology, that's all...

Comment: @DickHarfield Having said that, I really think that it would be very interesting if Christian and Islamic scholars share and discuss their views on Eschatology.

Comment: IMHO The latest edit brings this question into scope - thank you @Nathaniel.  I trust you accept his clarification, Wael?

Comment: @DickHarfield Yes no problem

Comment: This is a nice example of an apparently inappropriate question being transformed into one that is eminently suitable for this site. Very instructive.

Comment: I am tempted to suggest that this be reformatted as an overview question?  If some Christian scholars have looked into the topic as asked, or if a lot have, this has the potential to be a "shopping question" ... is overview a better approach?

Comment: This is a list question. I suggest re-wording it to "Are there any examples of works which contrast Christian and Islamic eschatology?" Then any single answer in the affirmative can be authoritative.

Comment: @Flimzy It would have to ask "who are or what works comment" to be a list. But it asks simply "Are there" which is technically just a Yes/No question. Which is of course not good either. But my point being he does not need to rephrase but simply add "If so(yes), what are some prime examples?"

Comment: @Flimzy Can't see version history now, so I realize now maybe my comment doesn't fit what you commented on, but is still applicable to th3 current version.

Answer (score 2):

No doubt there are Christian scholars who have studied Islamic eschatology but, although I have read a small number of books on Islam, I have not read any specifically about Islamic eschatology. However, a search of the internet found at least one interesting example from Joel Richardson, with enough preview information to suggest it could be recommended to the OP for his interest. I find that Richardson is not a scholar in the usual sense of the word, but a [Christian preacher and author](http://www.joelstrumpet.com/?page_id=2916).

Joel Richardson (*[Antichrist: Islam's Awaited Messiah](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=_lyXZu3d3OcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Islamic%20eschatology%20%22Christian%20scholarship%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9k7v5saLPAhWGFj4KHVZRBss4FBDoAQhOMAk#v=onepage&q&f=false)*) speaks (page xv) of having  Muslim friends all over the world and stresses (page xviii) that 'the purpose of this book is by no means to "bash" Muslims in any way.'

Richardson says (page 22) his book is "first and foremost a study of Islamic Eschatology (end-time belief) and those specific Islamic doctrines and practices that seem to correlate in quite an astonishing way to the biblical descriptions and prophecies of the last-days." He claims (page 23) that his is the first comprehensive popular study of Islamic Eschatology as it relates to biblical eschatology.

On the one hand, Richardson sees Islam as the future of the world, but on the other hand, his theme appears apocalyptic. Islam may be the future, but the future is a dark place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to say that Richardson, despite his amazing efforts in his book, was misguided about the Islamic Messiah, in fact he looked into the subject from a Shia perspective, but in reality, the Islamic Messiah is not Imam Mahdi (as Richardson suggest), he is in fact Jesus the son of Mary, and this is from an islamic view without any sectarian perspective, and this is how you can deal with the subject correctly. Imam Mahdi is an important figure in Islamic Eschatology, but NOT the Messiah. The Quran, without any doubt and clearly, refers to Jesus as the Messiah.

Comment: I suggest you watch this fascinating discussion, wich took place in the State University of Moscow, between two important scholars in Eschatology, a christian and a muslim (not sectarian), here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPHh3_oJeP8

Comment: I suspected that Richardson is not a good source, which is why I made the point that he is not a scholar in the usual sense.  As you know, I was initially confused as to just what you wanted to ask but, with  Nathaniel's help, I thought I had a handle on it. What I still could not tell from your question was whether you were looking for a serious, academic study or simply a popular one such as Richardson's.  You also did not say that you consider Shi'ite perspectives inappropriate., although of course they are Islamic perspectives in the broader sense.../

Comment: .../ I hope you can see how hard it is to give good answers to questions that I (we) have to interpret.

Comment: I know that it was not easy to answer my question, I thank you again, I imagine that you guessed that I am muslim, I wanted by this question to turn your attention to the fact that muslims and christians have a lot of common in terms of eschatology, and in the End of History, true muslims and true christians will be allied, I am personelly convicted by that, and i am convicted also that this End of History is around the corner, it is not so far.

Comment: Ellis Skolfield has made some comparisons between Christian and Islamic eschatology.